# Get first 5 records of each "group"

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table which looks like below

```
pid     server              time        day
89663   185.x.x.55:27015    463     2015-01-20
89684   185.x.x.55:27015    29      2015-01-20
61102   185.x.x.55:27015    309     2015-01-20
5748    185.x.x.55:27015    684     2015-01-20
317     79.x.x.40:27018     2410    2015-01-20
54499   79.x.x.40:27018     12921   2015-01-20
27176   80.x.x.12:27019     6711    2015-01-20
81564   80.x.x.12:27019     1095    2015-01-20
25628   185.x.x.55:27015    161     2015-01-20
```

PID is a player ID, time is in seconds

I want to make a query that shows how much time top 5 player of each server spend playing. I've written a query which does it:

```
SELECT `name`, `time`
FROM (
    SELECT `pid`, SUM(`time`) AS `time`
    FROM `stats_general`
    WHERE `server` = '{$ip}'
    AND `day` LIKE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-'),'%')
    GROUP BY `pid`
    ORDER BY `time` DESC
    LIMIT 0,5
) AS g
JOIN `stats_players` AS p ON g.pid = p.id
```

Unfortunately this query has one bad side. It shows top 5 for only one server. I want query to show top 5 of every server ( I don't wanna use UNION, it causes script executes a very long time.

Summing up. I want a query which will show top 5 ( time spend on server in current month ) of each server.

Answer (score 0):

Nest your query in another that gets the ip addresses;

```
SELECT `server` FROM `stats_general` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `server`
```